# Preconditions without code contract

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-4.0, refactoring

In ASP.net MVC (not necessarily limited to MVC, just an example), we always have preconditions in our action methods similar to the ones below:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(FooModel viewModel)
{
    if (viewModel == null)
    {
        throw new ArugmentNullException("viewModel");
    }

    if (viewModel.Foo < 1)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException();
    }

    // Perform real tasks on viewModel (e.g. map it to model, persist to database)

}
```

Now I know we can refactor the checks into a static method in a repository class:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(FooModel viewModel)
{
    if (FooModelRepostory.IsValid(viewModel)
    {
    }

    // Perform real tasks
}
```

In `FooModelRepository.cs`:

```
public static bool IsValid(FooModel viewModel)
{
    if (viewModel == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("viewModel");
    }

    if (viewModel.Foo < 1)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException();
    }

    // ...many more checks and throw exceptions accordingly

    // if we reach up to here, we are good, return true
    return true;
}
```

My question is, do we have a better way in refactoring the code without cluttering the repository with checks like this?

Comment: .Net 4.5 supports real contracts, see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264808.aspx

Comment: I am stuck at .NET 4.0 unfortunately :(

Comment: According to MSDN also available in 4.0

Comment: True, my memory never was the best. I've only started using it with 4.5.

Comment: Since I am inheriting an existing code base, I do not want to introduce a new dependency on code contracts. I just want to know whether my method above can be better refactored or not. Is there a way of achieving the same thing without code contracts

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything more clear that something is already provided by you. [Code Contracts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264808%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), yes, let you add declarative behavior to your program, but also hides clear logic. So, as anything, it has two sides: good and worse.

I would personally go with the solution you choose, so having simple control methods. 
The only thing that I would like to invite your attention on, is the fact that:

```
public static bool IsValid(FooModel viewModel)
{
 ...
}
```

returs `bool`, so in case of failure/negative response, I would expect `false`/`true` value to be returned and not exception raised. This is control flow of the program, so simple `return true` or `return false` is sufficient and *expected* from the consumer of your methods.

Comment: But if i return false when the `viewModel` is in an invalid state, I will have no way of informing the caller of the details of the invalid state, like which property is invalid.

Comment: @rexcfnghk: and how you signal to the caller about invalid state? With *type* of exception raised ?

Comment: No but as the example above, if I want to associate the invalid state with some more meaningful messages and send it back to the caller, how can I do so?

Comment: Question: but why ViewModel content validation code, you move *outside* of the ViewModel itself ? Why do not push responsibility of ViewModel fields validation to ViewModel itself ? If state "invalid" or "valid" is context sensitive, so you based on that you can style your html controls accordingly.

Comment: You are right, the `IsValid` method should probably reside in the `FooModel` class

Comment: @rexcfnghk: a part of it, your feedback of either value is acceptable or not has to be responded to the user just from ViewModel itself, imo.

Answer (score 0):

An other option would be to create validation classes. You just add objects of those classes to a list and asks the list if each Validation is valid. Just some of the advantages:

- The same validation can be reused for other controlers.
- If validations are added, the existing code leaves untouched (Open close/principle)
- Unit testing the validation is easier because you do not have to call the controller to see if it works
- If you do "find all reference" on a validation, you can see al the controlers that use the validation
- You can later choose if you want an exception of just a bool  without changing the validations.

More info and examples:
[enter link description here](http://www.siepman.nl/blog/post/2014/01/05/SOLID-validation-class-with-easy-logical-implication.aspx)